# siebel applications hadoop connectivity

Tags: hadoop, siebel

I would like to understand does hadoop support for siebel applications , can any body share experience in doing that. I looked for online documentation and not able to find any proper link to explain this so posting question here

I have and siebel application run with Oracle database, I would like to replace with HAdoop ..is it possible ?

Comment: What kind of support you are looking for? If you explained your requirements more detailed it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: added detail I have and siebel application run with Oracle database, I would like to replace with HAdoop ..is it possible ?

Comment: In short: no, you cannnot replace Oracle database with Hadoop. There is at least two reasons: Hadoop is not relational database and Siebel does not have Hadoop in the [list of supported RDBMS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11886_01/siebel/books/SRSP_81/SRSP_81.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

No is the answer.

Basically Hadoop isn't a database at all.

Hadoop is basically a distributed file system (HDFS) - it lets you store large amount of file data on a cloud of machines, handling data redundancy etc.

On top of that distributed file system it provides an API for processing all stored data using something called as Map-Reduce.